# Moving array segment within array

Tags: c#

If I have an array of items:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

I want to select a range of items and move them to another position in the array. For example:

```
1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8
```

Here the 5, 6, 7 segment has been moved to index 2.

What's the most efficient way of doing this, specifically to limit the number of extra array copies. I have a version working, but it's inefficient and forms a central role in my algorithm which I'm trying to optimise.

Thanks.

Comment: Any copy algorithm would be O(n) - each item inside region that is impacted need to be copied once... Unless you can avoid copying altogether there is not much optimizations you can do.

Comment: How large is your array? Do you also need to optimize for space?

Comment: Are you sure you need to optimize your current query? Is it unacceptably slow right now and did performance tests show you this is where the slowdown was? The time you are taking trying to figure out how to optimize this section of code could take you longer than the entire time you will save over the lifetime of the software.

Comment: @Scott. This particular part is repeated over 1,000,000 times per run so I want to optimise it as much as possible. It is certainly the slowest part of the overall operation by far.

Comment: It is possibly a more complex operation than it might first appear. I've been trying to wrap my head around it for hours. I have a version of it that works but it involves extracting the segment to be moved, creating an array of the remainder, and recombining these after picking the reinsert position. There must be a better way. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Do you always move backwards like that? Or do you sometimes move forwards? Forwards is much different (your indices don't really exist as they were)

Comment: The number of times it is called does not matter, simple example `int j = 0; for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { j = i;} Thread.Sleep(100000);` which took longer, the loop or the sleep? Look at what % did the profiler tells you it was spending in that section, you may be wrong about the time spent. Take a look at [this MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288073.aspx) and run a quick test. If I am wrong and you are right then your instincts where good. At least you will know instead of guessing.

Comment: What if you used a tree or other linked structure? Just a preliminary thought, but you may be able to move stuff around at lower cost, depending on whether you're taking elements by index or by value.  Then again, having to rejuggle tree elements on each move probably wouldn't be very time-efficient, either...

Comment: Traversing a linked list would be O(n), too, so that idea fails fairly quickly as well.

Comment: @KenoguLabz: in that case you'd want a skiplist.

Comment: But you'd have to re-jigger the skiplist each time, too, so that fails as well.  Any auxiliary index tracking has to be reindexed every time a sublist is moved.

Comment: I just realized that the linked list _does_ have one major advantage over the array: no array copying, which is one of the primary goals of the question.  The linked list solution would be much more _memory efficient_, which may eliminate Barguast's bottleneck.

Comment: @Scott - True. I checked this in the Performance Analysis on VS2012 and confirmed that it is spending most of its time in this array shuffling method. Just working my way through some suggestions to see if it makes a substantial difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to slice out the items which should move, then shift the existing members:

```
// T[] source
// int dest
// int start, end
T[] slice = new T[end - start];
Array.Copy(source, start, slice, 0, slice.Length);

if (dest < start)
{
    // push towards end
    Array.Copy(source, dest, source, dest + slice.Length, start - dest);
}
else
{
    // push towards start
    // who moves where? Assumes dest..dest+count goes left
    Array.Copy(source, end, source, dest, dest - start);
}

Array.Copy(slice, 0, source, dest, slice.Length);
```

Comment: After sitting down with a piece of paper and sketching it all out, I eventually ended up with code that pretty much matches this. I think it's probably the best solution. thanks.

Comment: It's ~350% faster under load testing :)

Comment: I don't know if this would change anything, but if you're using alue types you can look at `Buffer.BlockCopy` instead of `Array.Copy`.

Comment: If you really want to speed things up, Barguast, it looks to me like you can triple performance yet again over this Array.Copy scheme. You would just need to write the logic to do the shifting yourself, keeping shifted items in temp variables (just one or two would do) and deciding whether you wanted to shift things forward or backward, how you'd want to handle modular/wrap-around situations, etc. Shift methods would make nice extension methods for arrays.

Comment: It looks like performance using direct array access would be about 2-3 times better than calling Array.Copy() three times as in the above sample, depending on the specific implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a linked list.  Since you're moving subsections of a list, it'll be much more memory efficient to move the references on either end of the sublist than to copy each individual item in that same sublist.  Overall time-complexity is the same (Θ(n) to traverse a linked list, Θ(n) to copy an array segment), but you'll have better memory-complexity (constant n as opposed to Θ(n)) and fewer issues with continual memory allocation / deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have chosen an answer; but this question really got under my skin; to see if it's possible to write it another way.

So I came up with this code:

```
static int[] MoveSlice(int[] arr, int startIndex, int length, int newIndex)
{
    var delta = (int)Math.Abs(newIndex - startIndex);

    if (delta >= length)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var swap = arr[startIndex + i];
            arr[startIndex + i] = arr[newIndex + i];
            arr[newIndex + i] = swap;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var newStart = newIndex + length;

        for (var i = 0; i < delta; i++)
        {
            var swap = arr[newStart + i];
            arr[newStart + i] = arr[newIndex + i];
            arr[newIndex + i] = swap;
        }

        var l = (int)Math.Abs(length - delta);
        arr = MoveSlice(arr, newIndex + delta, l, newIndex);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

I did not test the performance yet. But I enjoyed solving it!

Perhaps you need to employ more code to check for possible errors on boundaries and the like.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to my first attempt before I posted this question. It is a deceptively tricky problem! Thanks.

Comment: If you have used that; was it useful? What about performance?

Comment: I only noticed that program spent more time in the method than I liked and wondered what the 'best' way of doing it was. I basically wanting to keep copies and swaps to a minimum. I haven't done a full comparison between my original method and my current one (see sixlettervariables' answer) but the code does run noticeably faster.

Comment: I expected it to be faster since there is no array copy. But I think - as far as my mind can go - swaps in here are at their minimum.

Comment: And remember (IMHO) when you test a method performance: 1 - exclude the first call (because of the things JIT do on first call) 2 - repeat it in a large number (say 100000) and divide whole spent time to 100000.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid making array copies for efficiency's sake, you can avoid them altogether.  You can use a minimum of variables for single values to move the items to their new destinations. Such an algorithm is very efficient on memory, and can be efficient also overall, though it obviously can't take advantage of native, efficient array copying.